# How do I register a user and sign in within same php function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a custom wordpress function to register a user, but I would also like them to be logged in after they register. The below only registers a user. You then have to login separately. Is it because The user is not actually registered by the time i try log them in?

```
function register_user_form() {
    $user_login = $_POST['currentUserName'];
    $user_email = $_POST['currentUserEmail'];
    $user_pass = $_POST['currentUserPassword'];

    $userdata = compact( 'user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass' );
    $user = wp_insert_user($userdata);
    $creds = array('user_login' => $user_login, 'user_password' => $user_pass, 'remember' => true);
    $user = wp_signon($creds);

}
add_action('wp_ajax_register_user_form', 'register_user_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_register_user_form', 'register_user_form');
```

Comment: Do you mean "sign in" instead of "sign up" in the title?

Comment: correct! just changed title - thanks

Comment: Seeing that this is being done via AJAX, are you reloading the page after the AJAX call is done? Otherwise I don't think this is going to work as is because I believe that the cookie that gets created when you log in won't be available until the next page load.

Comment: You can also check whether the sign-in attempt was successful or not by doing something like `error_log(print_r($user, true));` (make sure you enabled [debugging](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) first so you can see the output in the debug.log file.)

Comment: that was my thinking - that i first need to register a user (then reload page), then run the login function. but sure there's a way to combine them? think the default wordpress register does this

Comment: Your code is probably working, the issue is the JS side. You need to reload the window once the AJAX call is done (eg. `window.location.reload();`) for the authentication cookie to be loaded by the browser.

Comment: (But of course make sure that `$user` is a valid user before reloading, otherwise you'll want to show an error message to let the visitor know that something went wrong.)

Comment: Also, you should be using either [wp_die()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/) or [die()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) at the end of your PHP function as that's required by WordPress when working with their AJAX API (see [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/enqueuing/#ajax-action)).

Comment: @cabrerahector thanks, but can i run window.location.reload() then wp_signon in the same function? how risky is it assigning the username/password in a cookie, then logging them in after the page reloads, then clearing the cookie immediately?